How to put input value (type=text) in HTML as JavaScript function result
I'm curious on how to put input value (input=text) in HTML as JS function result.
I'm currently using this JavaScript function;
function maketeststring(length) {
    let result = '';
    const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    const charactersLength = characters.length;
    let counter = 0;
    while (counter < length) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
      counter += 1;
    }
    return result;
}
console.log(maketeststring(16));

This is my input code in HTML;
<input class="test_string" type="text" id="teststring" readonly;>
Result of function 'maketeststring' is always regenerating when user is refreshing website (for example when you open website for 1st time it will be "IR5xOxAq30ZcOGku", when you refresh website it will regenerate in "Nnd2QlgSVFkjgthY". I want my input value to change whenever users is refreshing website. Thanks in advance!

you mean change console.log(maketeststring(16)); to document.getElementById('teststring').value = maketeststring(16); ?

It's working perfectly now, but can you help me display it in console as well? I tried adding console.log(maketeststring(16)) under the document.getElementByID('teststring').value = maketeststring(16) line. On my website one string is showed, but in my console log string is not matching. @Godot

I changed my comment to an answer to show how to show in the input AND the console

Answering since you have additional requirements
If you want to show the string in the field AND in console, then you need to save the result since each time you call the function you get a new string
I wrap in a DOMContentLoaded to allow the script to be placed in the head before the HTML elements


function maketeststring(length) {
  let result = '';
  const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
  const charactersLength = characters.length;
  let counter = 0;
  while (counter < length) {
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    counter += 1;
  }
  return result;
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { // when page elements are available
  const saveString = maketeststring(16); // save the result
  console.log(saveString); // show it in console
  document.getElementById('teststring').value = saveString;
});
<input class="test_string" type="text" id="teststring" readonly;>




You can get and set the value of an input element through the value property.
In your case:
document.getElementById("teststring").value = "new value";

You can read more about input element in this document:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input
